# Circular Tabs/Navigation in Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have been using bootstrap for my blog website and I am incorporating the tabs widget. I don't really like how it looks. Is there a way to get a nice circular type tab in bootstrap like the ones shown below?

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the `.nav-pills` class instead of the `.nav-tabs` class.

http://getbootstrap.com/components/#nav

Comment: Do you know if there is a way to change the color radius of the Pill?